# How to always get the latest version of an specific dependency in maven 3.x?

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I have a maven project with large pom file, I want one of my dependencies to be always the latest version which is deployed to our local antifactory server.

the name of this dependency is "WebInfra" and I use maven 3.x so the "LATEST" keyword is not working for me.

I'll put the pom file here and I'll be happy to find a solution for this problem. I need other dependencies to stay in their fixed version and only this dependency should upgraded to the latest version each time I call `mvn clean deploy` on it.
I see ["Versions Maven Plugin"](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) and set its includes and excludes but not working for me :
I have webinfra-1.jar and then I deployed webinfra-2.0-SNAPSHOT into artifactory server but when I run mvn versions:use-latest-versions nothing happens. I expect my pom change into version 2.0-snapshot. What's going wrong here ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.dpdouran.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>WebERP</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>WebERP</name>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>Douranrepository</id>
      <name>Douranrepository</name>
      <url>http://192.168.100.243:8082/artifactory/Douranrepository/</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>Douranrepository</id>
      <name>Douranrepository</name>
      <url>http://192.168.100.243:8082/artifactory/Douranrepository/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <properties>
    <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
    <gwtVersion>2.5.1</gwtVersion>
    <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Defaults -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- thirdparties -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thirdparty.grouped</groupId>
      <artifactId>Thridparty</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Douran artifacts -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.accounting</groupId>
      <artifactId>accounting</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.bi</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebAnalytic</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.bi</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebDashboard</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.bi</groupId>
      <artifactId>ireport</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.bi</groupId>
      <artifactId>reporting</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebCommon</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>baseinfo</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>coding</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>common</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>custom-editor</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>filemanager</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>formula</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>image</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>oa</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>webfilemanager</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>weboa</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.custom</groupId>
      <artifactId>BFonts</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.custom</groupId>
      <artifactId>DecisionTable</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.custom</groupId>
      <artifactId>ITIL</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.custom</groupId>
      <artifactId>configfiles</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.custom</groupId>
      <artifactId>db</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.custom</groupId>
      <artifactId>dynamicreports</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.custom</groupId>
      <artifactId>encrypt</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.humanresource</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_Attendanc</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.humanresource</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_Command</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.humanresource</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_Common</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.humanresource</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_Evaluation</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.humanresource</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_Knowledge</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.humanresource</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_PayRoll</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.humanresource</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_Personnel</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.humanresource</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_Pishnehadat</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.humanresource</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_Recruitment</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.humanresource</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_Refahi</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.humanresource</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_Training</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.humanresource</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebHumanResource</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.humanresource</groupId>
      <artifactId>organizationchart</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infrastructure</groupId>
      <artifactId>Infra</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infrastructure</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebInfra</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infrastructure</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebInfraService</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infrastructure</groupId>
      <artifactId>webskin</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.logistics</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebSupport</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.logistics</groupId>
      <artifactId>production</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.logistics</groupId>
      <artifactId>projectmanagement</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.logistics</groupId>
      <artifactId>realestate</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.logistics</groupId>
      <artifactId>risk_management</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.logistics</groupId>
      <artifactId>support</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.network</groupId>
      <artifactId>Manager</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.network</groupId>
      <artifactId>NetworkCommon</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.network</groupId>
      <artifactId>NetworkGraph</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.network</groupId>
      <artifactId>NetworkMonitoringUI</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.network</groupId>
      <artifactId>NetworkUtil</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.network</groupId>
      <artifactId>NetworkWebService</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.network</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebNetworkDiscovery</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.network</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebNetworkMonitoring</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.network</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebStockChart</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.network</groupId>
      <artifactId>websocket-api</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.workflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebCartable</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.workflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>cartable</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.workflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>workflow</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.workflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>webworkflow</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>org.dpdouran.infrastructure:*</include>
          </includes>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils</exclude>
            <exclude>com.google.gwt:*</exclude>
            <exclude>javax.validation:*</exclude>
            <exclude>org.codehaus.mojo:*</exclude>
            <exclude>org.apache.maven.plugins:*</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>



      <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <!-- <goal>test</goal>
              <goal>i18n</goal>
              <goal>generateAsync</goal> -->
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see 
          gwt-maven-plugin documentation at codehaus.org -->
        <configuration>
          <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx8192M -Xss2048M </extraJvmArgs>
          <!-- -Dfoo=bar -->
          <runTarget>WebERP.html</runTarget>
          <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
          <!-- <i18nMessagesBundle>org.dpdouran.web.client.Messages</i18nMessagesBundle> -->
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exploded</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I tried Versions Maven Plugin with excludes and includes but still not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have two separate runs of Maven:

1. Update the version with the versions maven plugin on command line.
2. Run something like `mvn clean verify` to build the project.

You cannot change the version while building the project.

BTW: You configured Java 5. Are you really sure you want this?

Comment: Thanks J Fabian, for the first step I run  `mvn versions:use-latest-versions` but after it ended successfully the version of WebInfra is still 1. I close and reopen the pom file for examination and it is still version 1 and not updated to version 2. This happens while I can see the version 2 in Jfrog Artifactory web UI on browser.
BTW: There is still some places in the world that forces developers to use GWT 2.5.1 and java 5 ;) It is an old big ERP project and I'm trying to change it to maven structure and planning to upgrade it to new technologies but there are customers for it and so on ...